# Variable not passing to .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can someone please point out to me what I am guessing is very simple error in my script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pn = $("#search");
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("data.asp?prodref= #result"+pn);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="search">92K002</p>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to pass the text from `<p id="search">92K002</p>` to `.load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pn = $("#search");
```

Is an entire jQuery object. You need to grab the `.text()` from it.

```
var pn = $("#search").text();
```

An easy way to see this is to check the URL being loaded via the Network tab in your browsers console.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but its still not working. It is picking up the URL just not adding the `pn` variable.

Comment: What did the network tab say? Can you copy and paste the URL to your browser and yield the proper URL?

Comment: Taking what @SterlingArcher suggested sort of works, if I remove the`#result`. So `$(document).ready(function(){
    var pn = $("#search").text();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+pn);
    });
});` But where do I declare the element I want

Comment: @JonathanGriffin It should be at the end of the string:  `$("#div1").load("data.asp?prodref="+pn+" #result");`